# What is the syntax of @if ($articles!= null) in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3,
There is something wrong in the view below:

controller：

```
$user=\Auth::user();
$articles = $user->articles;
return view('articles.index',  compact('articles'));
```

view:

```
@if ($articles!= null)
<p>Yes</p>
@else
<p>No</p>
@endif
```

Question:
When no articles return,it still show "Yes".
Is `$articles!= null` not right?

Comment: `articles.index` !== `articles`?

Comment: In this case, `$articles` can be anything but not null.  You may check for an empty array instead: `if ($articles->count() > 0)`

Comment: Did you try `is_null($articles)` or `empty($articles) ` ?

Comment: Technically don't even need the `> 0` @revo but helps for verbosity.

Comment: You should call it readability not verbosity @JaredEitnier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$user->articles` is most likely a `Collection` which is why it doesn't pass your `null` check. `$articles` is probably returning an empty Collection which is not the same as `null`.

Instead you want to check for `$articles->count()` or `$articles->isEmpty()`. Your view would look like:

```
@if (!$articles->isEmpty())
    <p>Yes</p>
@else
    <p>No</p>
@endif
```

or

```
@if ($articles->count())
    <p>Yes</p>
@else
    <p>No</p>
@endif
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-count or https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-isempty